# Android : failed to start emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am unable to start my android emulator in eclipse . I get hit with the following error message always

```
"Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/Users/anandmadhusoodanan/Desktop/Assignments/Spring-2012/Embedded_Systems_Programming/android-sdk-macosx//tools/emulator": error=1, Operation not permitted" where
 "/Users/anandmadhusoodanan/Desktop/Assignments/Spring-2012/Embedded_Systems_Programming/android-sdk-macosx" is the path of my sdk.
```

I have tried re-installing the ADT plug-in, the sdk and even eclipse.
I am using Mac OS.

Comment: ls -l /Users/anandmadhusoodanan/Desktop/Assignments/Spring-2012/Embedded_Systems_Programming/android-sdk-macosx//tools/emulator ?

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x@ 1 anandmadhusoodanan  staff  45752 Mar 16 12:19 /Users/anandmadhusoodanan/Desktop/Assignments/Spring-2012/Embedded_Systems_Programming/android-sdk-macosx//tools/emulator

Comment: Size is correct. But the '@' indicates that it's a symlink and it shouldn't.

Comment: @dtmilano: What do i do to get it working again? I've tried re-installing the sdk and the ADT plugin, but to no avail

Comment: The original package doesn't have a symlink for emulator. So be sure you are downloading the official one.

Comment: i tried to download the sdk package on my ubuntu installation. Surprising thing here is that, there is no @(symlink) shown when i check the permissions after extracting. So does this mean it is a problem with my Mac??

Comment: My comment was based on OSX info

Comment: @dtmilano: i'm sure i'm downloading the official sdk version. Any other fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @ symbol indicates that there are extended attributes for the files in question. To verify the extended attributes applied to the files use:

```
ls -l@
```

You'll probably find (as I did) that there is a com.apple.quarantine attribute on the files which can be removed with:

```
xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine sdkFolder
```

Where sdkFolder should be replaced with the name of the folder you extracted the SDK to.

Comment: THANKS A MILLIONNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN. Now i wont have to log-in to ubuntu to use eclipse !!!

Comment: I run into this problem too, the Eclipse just would not launch. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have execute permissions on the emulator

Try

```
$chmod 755 emulator
```