# Failed to start emulator in Linux

Tags: android, android-emulator, file-permissions, ubuntu-12.04

The problem is that,I switched form windows to linux[ubuntu 12.04] and I'm using android emulator for android programming with eclipse. and when I tried to run my adv emulator it exits with this message:

```
Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/home/lenovo/Desktop/adt-bundle-linux/sdk//tools/emulator": error=13, Permission denied.
```

the same problem was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935270/android-failed-to-start-emulator) for iOS but in that case it was error:1. I read the solution but could not implement it because I could not understand it and also I'm new for linux. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 as my os.
It would be great if some buddy could help me...

Answer (score 11):

Open command prompt and type below commands.

First#

`su root` it will ask for password if you given, enter your password,

Second#

`chmod -R 777 '/home/android-sdk-linux/'`  (path of your sdk)

press enter and again try to start your emulator.

hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix permissions:

```
sudo chown -R lenovo:lenovo /home/lenovo/Desktop/adt-bundle-linux
sudo chmod +x /home/lenovo/Desktop/adt-bundle-linux/sdk/tools/emulator
```

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys the problem has been solved. It was due to incomplete upgrade of the OS. I solved it by just upgrading the OS. The main problem was that the adt-bundle for linux was for 32 bit architecture and to run it in 64 bit arch. the libraries of ubuntu must be updated.